# Can the "--skip-client" entity parameter be applied to only some entities?

Tags: jhipster

Using Jhipster 7.0.1, I'd like to generate entities where only a select few have their client-side-code generated. Generation without the client-side works as expected at first, but any subsequent entities with a frontend will force *all* entities to have a their client-side code generated.

---

**To replicate the issue:**

- Generate an entity without a frontend. This correctly creates **only** server-sided code. `jhipster entity Foo --skip-client`
- Generate an entity normally. `jhipster entity Bar`

**For the test, entities were not created with any relationships.*

After generation, both `Foo`, and `Bar` will have client-side code generated. The log entry seems to highlight the issue:

> Found the .jhipster\Foo.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!

---

When client-side only entities are created, its seems that there's no configuration saved in the `.jhipster\Foo.json` files to accommodate the `--skip-client` parameter. I could simply delete the json files of server-side only entities and thier corresponding entries in `.yo-rc.json`, but I'm concerned I'll run into issues upgrading Jhipster if they've been removed. Is there a better way I can accomplish this?

---

**Edit:**
I may have found a solution. Adding both `"skipClient"` & `"skipServer"` entries to every .jhipster/*.json file seems to resolve the issue.

**.jhipster\Foo.json**

```
{
  "name": "Foo",
  "skipClient": true,
  "skipServer": false
}
```

I believe this may be a bug where Jhipster is not adding the configuration on its own.

Comment: Yes it's probably a bug, you should report it on github.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks, I'll open a ticket now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding both `"skipClient"` & `"skipServer"` entries manually to every .jhipster/*.json file seems to resolve the issue.

**.jhipster\Foo.json**

```
{
  "name": "Foo",
  "skipClient": true,
  "skipServer": false
}
```

I believe this may be a bug where Jhipster is not adding the configuration on its own.

I opened a ticket here: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/15366